# How to constraint a view to overlap another view in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I am overlapping an ImageView on top  of a View in a RelativeLayout.

something like this:

[image] 
1

Where the middle white circle(ImageView) is overlapping the white vertical border(View).

But for some reason I am not managing to **constraint** the circle above the z position of the white border. and if the border moves say to the right side of the screen, I want the circle to move there too. but instead the circle always remains in the center regardless to the position of the border.
How do I this in a RelativeLayout?

T.I.A

Answer (score 0):

You can make like:
AlignLeftOf the border
Then code: circle.translationX( circle_width/2)
(and a bit of justification, it should be good)

Comment: hi, it works pretty nice when the border moves to the right edge of the screen but if  the border moves to the edge left of the screen, the circle disapears